# How can I annex a puppet city in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

When I conquered a city state I chose to turn it into a puppet.  The dialogue promised that I'd be able to annex it at any point.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just left click it =)

Comment: That brings up the city screen, but it's still in a puppet state - I can't change production.

Comment: Hmm.. this always asked me if I wanted to annex the city now. Strange.

Comment: Solved!  See my comment to CJM's answer.

Comment: @Tommy, if a city is still in a state of revolt, it won't be able to produce anything.  This doesn't sound like your problem, but maybe.

Answer (score 3):

As Jens says, if you click on the city name, a dialog box should pop up asking if you want to annex the city, or if you want to leave it as a puppet (and it should indicate the Happiness impact of such a decision).

Is this not the case for you?

Comment: Aha!  I've been playing using the strategic view because my computer can't really handle the graphics.  Clicking on the city in the normal view does what you say.  Thanks.